# Error using library react-native-call-detection

Tags: android, ios, react-native, gradle

I am trying to use the [react-native-call-detection](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-call-detection) library to get the incoming call number.

But when I start the android emulator this low error appears.

I have already run `react-native unlink react-native-call-detection`, but the error continues. Having identify the other mistakes but to no avail!

If I completely remove `react-native-call-detection` then the emulator opens without any error.

Can someone help me please?

Thanks.

```
Microsoft Windows [versão 10.0.18363.535]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. Todos os direitos reservados.

L:\wAPP\reactCall>react-native run-android
error React Native CLI uses autolinking for native dependencies, but the following modules are linked manually: 
  - react-native-call-detection (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-call-detection")
This is likely happening when upgrading React Native from below 0.60 to 0.60 or above. Going forward, you can unlink this dependency via "react-native unlink <dependency>" and it will be included in your app automatically. If a library isn't compatible with autolinking, disregard this message and notify the library maintainers.
Read more about autolinking: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/autolinking.md
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 1645 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...

> Task :app:processDebugManifest FAILED

See http://g.co/androidstudio/manifest-merger for more information about the manifest merger.


Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
21 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 18 up-to-date
L:\wAPP\reactCall\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:11:7-34 Error:
        Attribute application@allowBackup value=(false) from AndroidManifest.xml:11:7-34
        is also present at [:react-native-call-detection] AndroidManifest.xml:14:9-35 value=(true).
        Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:allowBackup"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:7:5-117 to override.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@allowBackup value=(false) from AndroidManifest.xml:11:7-34
        is also present at [:react-native-call-detection] AndroidManifest.xml:14:9-35 value=(true).
        Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:allowBackup"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:7:5-117 to override.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.      
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
L:\wAPP\reactCall\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:11:7-34 Error:
        Attribute application@allowBackup value=(false) from AndroidManifest.xml:11:7-34
        is also present at [:react-native-call-detection] AndroidManifest.xml:14:9-35 value=(true).
        Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:allowBackup"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:7:5-117 to override.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@allowBackup value=(false) from AndroidManifest.xml:11:7-34
        is also present at [:react-native-call-detection] AndroidManifest.xml:14:9-35 value=(true).
        Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:allowBackup"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:7:5-117 to override.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7s

    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:610:11)
    at execFileSync (child_process.js:628:15)
    at runOnAllDevices (L:\wAPP\reactCall\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:94:39)
    at buildAndRun (L:\wAPP\reactCall\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:158:41)
    at L:\wAPP\reactCall\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:125:12
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (L:\wAPP\reactCall\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:164:9)        

L:\wAPP\reactCall>
```

Comment: You have tagged this iOS, but it isn't possible to get the incoming number on iOS.

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes, is possible: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FsK6sQgRDdE

Comment: Read the description of that video; both devices must have truecaller installed and if you are calling from iOS you must make the call from truecaller; The truecaller app sends the caller details to their own server which then sends a push to the destination device. An app on iOS can not access the incoming number directly.

Comment: If TrueCaller was made in IOS and recognizes the number received, why can't I do the same?

Comment: Truecaller doesn't "recognise" the number, it knows the number since the calling device told the truecaller server who it was and what number it was calling, so the server could notify the called device via a push notification.  If it make the call from a phone without truecaller installed or from the native iOS phone app on an iPhone

Comment: @Paulw11 Is there no hybrid solution to pick up the incoming call number on IOS?

Comment: No, that would be a privacy violation. You can register names and numbers for iOS to recognise using a CallKit directory extension but your code cannot know the details of any incoming calls

Answer (score 0):

Try edit /android/app/main/AndroidManifest.xml in manifest tag at the top of the file add `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` before package name.

In application tag remove `android:allowBackup="false"` and add `tools:replace="android:allowBackup"`

And Don't forget require READ_PHONE_STATE permission by add  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />`